# How do I install all standard fonts that come with Ubuntu on Ubuntu Server

Tags: fonts

I'd like to install all fonts that come with a regular installation of Ubuntu Desktop on a Ubuntu Server install.

Specifically, I would like all web-fonts to be available for chrome (CEF) to be able to render websites correctly. I have found that installing `fonts-indic` solves the problem for the website I was having issues with. However, I'd like to be able to solve this problem once and for all.

I'm assuming that a pristine Ubuntu Desktop installation would have enough fonts to more or less achieve this, while Ubuntu Server installs only a small handful of fonts by default (if any - it is possible what I see is installed by something else I did on the server). I'm hoping there is a package such as `fonts-common` or some such, which installs a curated list of fonts forming a reasonable basis and provides good unicode coverage, as well as perhaps includes fonts that websites may typically depend on.

Is there an apt package which can be used to do this?

Answer (score 2):

The ubuntu software repositories indeed contain several font packages. Their name starts with `fonts-`.

If you are looking for a single metapackage that installs all fonts that otherwise are installed along with `ubuntu-desktop` or `ubuntu-minimal`, then, no, there is not, because a request for such package would be very uncommon.